# Upper bounding the Frobenius norm of difference of two left-singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have two $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$, with SVD $A=U_A\Sigma_A V_A^\top,B=U_B\Sigma_B V_B^\top$, where $U_A\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}, U_B\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times k}, \Sigma_B\in\mathcal{M}_{k\times k}$ with $k<n$(then scales of the rest are determined). Let $U_A^k=U_A(:,1:k)$ be the first $k$ columns of $U_A$.

Now I want to upper bounding the difference between $U_A^k$ and $U_B$, up to orthogonal transformations, in terms of $||A-B||_2$ and possibly singular values of $B$, i.e. $$\min_{R\in\mathcal{O}_k}||U_A^k-U_BR||_F\leq f(||A-B||_2,\Sigma_B)$$

for some function $f$, but I don't have a clue where to start. Any help, including a possible direction, is desired.